# ¿Cómo poner un mensaje de error en R?

Tags: r

Estoy programando una función, en donde una de las entradas deben ser "A" o "B". ¿Cómo puedo hacer que cuando se inserte un valor distinto a "A" o "B", me deuelva un mensaje de error, diciendo (la entrada 3 del vector debe ser "A" o "B" )?

Answer (score 3):

El mensaje lo puedes mostrar con la funcion [stop o warning](http://rfunction.com/archives/1377) despues de realizar la validacion:

```
stop("la entrada 3 del vector debe ser A o B")
```

o

```
warning("la entrada 3 del vector debe ser A o B")
```

Ejemplo:

```
miFuncion<-function(a, b)
{
 cat("valor a = ",a, "\n")
 cat("valor b = ",b, "\n")
 A<-100
 B<-12
 if(a != A | b != B){
  cat("la entrada 3 del vector debe ser A o B")
  stop("la entrada 3 del vector debe ser A o B")
 }else{
  cat("los valores coinciden A = ",a, ",B = ", b)
 }
}
# define valores
a<-101
b<-11
# llama la funcion!
m<-miFuncion(a,b)
```